# General::ivar: ... is not a valid variable

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have been trying to decipher what this output means, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Does anybody know what is going on here?

[image]

I have even tried running the lines one by one and the errors only show up when the final line (show) is executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stepping through the lines individually by themselves would not show you what is going on, you have to take apart the statement that is giving you the trouble:  in this case, `Show[p1, p2[1,1]`.  By themselves, neither `p1` nor `Show` should give you trouble, which leads to the conclusion that it must be `p2[1,1]`.  This is born out by running that by itself, which generates the same error.

This generates an error because of how `Plot`, `Plot3D`, etc evaluate the function argument.  In general, they essentially do a `Replace` on the text of the function and may not expand function calls. A simple fix is to rewrite `p2` as

```
p2[x0_, y0_] := Plot3D[Evaluate[p[x, y, x0, y0]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

which gets rid of the errors.  `Evaluate` ensures that function is evaluated symbolically before `Plot3D` gets a hold of it avoiding any mishandling. I wish I had a better idea of when to use `Evaluate` in these cases, but if in general if you are getting errors from a plotting function like these, then it is most likely mishandling the function.

Comment: Good answer, Evaluate is the way to fix this. One comment I would make is that, technically, it is not actually Replace that is effectively used to set values for x and y here. It is Block. That's why this works, despite p not being present in the literal first argument to Plot: e = p^2; Plot[e, {p, 0, 1}]

Comment: @Andrew, well I wasn't sure exactly what causes this problem, and it seemed to behave a bit like Replace, but wrapping everything in a Block makes a lot sense both in regards to the error and just good practice.